apexcharts.js tickPlacement:on messes tooltip formatter
        xaxis: {
          type: 'category',
          tickPlacement: 'on',
          range: 10, 
          labels: {
            show: true,              
            formatter: function(val) {
              return dayjs(val).format("MMM")
            }
          },
          group: {
            style: {
              fontSize: '10px',
              fontWeight: 700
            },
            //groups: [{ title: '2023', cols: 3 },{ title: '2024', cols: 7 }]
            groups: <?php echo $mos_cnt_response;?>
         }
        },

    tooltip: {
      x: {
        formatter: function(val) {
          return dayjs(val).format("MMM") + " " + dayjs(val).format("YYYY")
        }  
      }
    },

`
Removing: tickPlacement: 'on', the correct tooltip data is shown. Also removes the toolbar which I need it to scroll it horizontally coz I added "range: 10" to show initial 10 recent data.
Not removing it messes up the tooltip formatter date into "Dec 1969".
Is there any fix?

In the configuration you have, with the tickPlacement: 'on' option, the x axis type is changed automatically to numeric, which enables the range option (range is a numeric value for max-min, with no meaning or effect for a category axis) but has as an undesired effect that the x formatter gets as its first parameter, val, the (y) value of the bar not its (x) label. The x labels can still be retrieved from the second parameter in the call to formatter.

Alternatively, if the dates on the x axis don't have gaps between them, a more canonical solution would be to set the xaxis type to  'datetime' and set range in milliseconds. For both alternatives, a solution here on stackoverflow, would require you to provide a runnable example, many of the other options and the structure of your data are essential for a complete, tested solution.
